# I got InternalError when I use getSharedPreferences in android 7.1

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I got java internal error when I use "getSharedPreferences" android api.
This is my code:

```
private int getByte() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = m_ctx.getSharedPreferences("config", 0);
    ...
}
```

but I find the android source code and got below:

```
private void startLoadFromDisk() {
    synchronized (this) {
        mLoaded = false;
    }
    new Thread("SharedPreferencesImpl-load") {
        public void run() {
            loadFromDisk();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I donnot know which is wrong? Thank you very much!

The log is:

```
java.lang.InternalError:
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method:0)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.startLoadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:98)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:91)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:360)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:349)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**,
Instead using mCtx you can try using getApplicationContext()..

(i,e).

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("config", 0);
```